# Qt5.4/QML: How to determine wether the orientation of the screen is inverted or not

Tags: c++, ios, qt, orientation, qml

I'm creating a iOS video camera app using Qt5.4.
For this I need to determine the current orientation of the device to rotate the video in the `VideoOutput` element.

As we can see there's a [`autoOrientation` property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html#autoOrientation-prop) but it doesn't work as I expect: if I keep switching the orientation it starts to have a weird behaviour i.e. setting the wrong orientation.

Then I tried to apply the rotation based on the `Screen.primaryOrientation` property:
Copying the function defined in [this example](https://github.com/openwebos/qt/blob/master/examples/declarative/screenorientation/Core/screenorientation.js), I've a created a similar version, which you can find [here](http://pastebin.com/R62tKNJK).

I call it every time `width` or `height` changes, like this:

```
onWidthChanged: { video.orientation = changeOrientation(); }
onHeightChanged: { video.orientation = changeOrientation(); }
```

However, it seems that the **Inverted** orientations are completely ignored, which is strange since they are listed in [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ScreenOrientation-enum).

Anyone has any idea about why it's happening?

UPDATE:
I could isolate the problem when using autoOrientation, basically there's a menu on top of the VideoOutput, the menu is a RowLayout, it's visible only if the user clicks on the menu icon, and only if the user clicks on the menu icon the orientation gets messy.

However, in any situation the InvertedPortrait is not recognized.

Comment: Just my two cents. I've experienced problems with `autoOrientation` only when used with `GridLayout`s and the `flow` property. In all other cases, apart from a syntax  error in Qt Creator, it worked fine. I've only tested on an iPad, though. I don't know for other iOS devices.

Comment: Almost the same situation, I'll update the question.